# How could I maintain split layout when deleting buffers?

Tags: buffers, split

I opened 5 buffers and in one of them I use the command `:vs` to split the current buffer screen into two.
When I use the command `<leader>d` to close one of the splitted buffers, the consequence is that the splitted window is also closed along with the buffer to be closed. I would like to close the buffer without impacting the split pattern of my screen.

For example, "buffer #1" and "buffer #2" are displayed in my current screen, I would like to close "buffer #1" with `<leader>d` and leave the screen to be a split of "buffer #3" and "buffer #2" instead of a not splitted screen with only "buffer #2" on it.

Is that requirement accessible?

Comment: Does `:bnext` in the window that you want to change buffers not solve this? What i mean is, what is missing from `:bnext` that a solution to your problem would have?

Comment: I need to close that buffer instead of switch to others. when use airline, the titles of the opened buffers always exists. And when use ```:bnext``` I will still switch to the that buffer that I would like to close. I need a method to close a buffer without impacting the split status of my screen. Hope I made my problem clear :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by « close a buffer »—it can be hidden, deleted, or wiped out (as well as displayed in a window). Do you mean you want to delete the buffer and move to the next one?

Comment: yes, I would like to save the contents to file and delete the buffer, and I could recreate it if I need. I wish the place where the deleted buffer was displayed to be occupied with other buffers if any exists and I could still have that split screen.

Comment: Then you should look at `:bd`.

Comment: I run the command ```:bd``` and the buffer deleted, but the split window also disappears. I do want to keep the screen split and delete the buffer. Maybe I did not make it clear. You may try to open a file named ```a.txt``` with vim, run the command ```:vs b.txt``` and then run your ```:bd```. The result is that window is no long split. Could I delete the buffer while keep the split ?

Answer (score 4):

[vim-bbye](https://github.com/moll/vim-bbye) does exactly what you're looking for. It provides `:Bdelete` and `:Bwipeout`, which are variants of `:bdelete` and `:bwipeout` that will delete the buffer **but maintain the split and switch to another buffer**, preserving your current split layout.

I personally mapped `:Bdelete` like so:

```
nnoremap <Leader>d :Bdelete<CR>
```

It's a terrific and simple plugin; I've been using it for over a year now.

Comment: Many thanks, that is very helpful. By the way, when I create a terminal in the last buffer ```:ter``` and then delete the buffer without close the terminal first, the buffer got removed but the terminal still exists as the last thing remained in the screen. Do you have some idea on how I could close the terminal when the last buffer is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following solution:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>d  :enew \| bd#<Return>
```

Limitation: you can not run this on unnamed buffer without affecting the split. If this is a concern, you may want to replace `enew` with `e .` etc.